# Error 0xFFFD0000 while running powershell script in task sequence

Tags: powershell, sccm

I am trying to run a powershell script during a Windows 10 inplace upgrade task sequence. The script exports Win 10 start menu tiles of the users and then imports them after upgrade.
I am getting error **0xFFFD0000** while exporting. The command lines I have used to run the script in TS are

```
powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -File
```

and

```
Export_startmenulayout.ps1
```

But everything fails.

Could someone please help.

Comment: Which user does the task run as? Does it access network resources? [See a blog post I wrote about this error](https://www.briantist.com/errors/scheduled-task-powershell-0xfffd0000/).

Comment: Is this a run commandline step or an application/program?

Comment: It uses system admin account which is used by SCCM to install any package or application, yes, it runs from distribution point..works as network resource..i tried your blog..but still not fix..

Comment: @Syberdoor..This is a powershell script to export startmenulayout of the user before running task sequence to upgrade the OS

Comment: this error is sadly very hard to debug, is there any possibility that the path where the layout is exported to is not accessible by the system account? or is it a local path?

Comment: `0XFFFD0000` usually means there is something wrong with a path. You could try `%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -NoLogo -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "<FULL PATH OF THE Export_startmenulayout.ps1 FILE>"`.
However, since you are not showing us what the `Export_startmenulayout.ps1` does and how it handles paths for exporting, there is no way to answer your question.

Comment: @Theo if this is an sccm program there is not really a full path. sccm uses a concept where it copies the files to a local cache (with random folder name) and sets the workingdir accordingly so you can only use relative paths. .\Export_startmenulayout.ps1 might be necessary though.

Comment: @Theo.. This is the command i am trying to run- Export-StartLayout –path $env:LOCALAPPDATA\LayoutModification.xml.. Issue now has changed..now i am not getting error code mentioned in the title of the question..now MY task sequence goes through without error but it does not export the layout xml file to %localappdat% location of the user..however script works and create the export while run manually

Comment: @Syberdoor..any suggestion???

Comment: What user is running the task sequence? Is that a different user than the currently logged-on user? In that case `$env:LocalAppdata` will get you the wrong path. I think you can get the current logged on user (and not the one that is running the script) with `Get-WMIObject -class Win32_ComputerSystem | select -expandproperty username`. This will return the username in `domain\username` format. Then you calculate the LOCALAPPDATA path for that user.

Comment: I don't have a suggestion for this specific error but in general as for debugging I would enable (if you don't already have) debugging cmd support for the bootimage (works in the whole ts) then let it crash and start the cmd with f8. from there try to manually run the file and see if you can get a better error reporting. You can probably not see the path (maybe in one of the logs?) but it would be somewhere in C:\windows\ccmcache normally and at this point there should not be too many subfolders

Comment: Just saw you said the problem changed. As TS uses system account by default it would not be in your users localappdata but in systems (C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local) in general for debugging purposes you should use something not user or environmen variable dependent for a path. If it works for a path like C:\test (be sure to create the folder first if the export command cnanot do it (don't know if it can)) then move on to the more complex one

Comment: @Syberdoor  i am not using the script in TS, i have created a package and a application for this script in sccm, and  again package method does not create any export at all, however application does create xml export but it is blank..i create a try and catch function in the script to capture the error and this is what is get from there...error from script is .

Comment: .Export-StartLayout : Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a 
COM component.
At C:\WINDOWS\ccmcache\9\Export_startmenulayout.ps1:5 char:1
+ Export-StartLayout –path c:\windows\LayoutModification.xml
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Export-StartLayout], COMExcep 
   tion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,Micr 
   osoft.Windows.StartLayout.Commands.ExportStartLayoutCommand

Comment: I know that you use a package but as you can see in the error this does not mean it does not download the ps1 to your drive. After pressing f8 you can manually go to C:\WINDOWS\ccmcache\9\ and run Export_startmenulayout.ps1 (it will not always be 9 but there will not be too many folders probably) also you don't even need to run the script maybe but just start powershell and run the Export-StartLayout command in the same way and experiment with the paths etc to learn something. Sorry I cannot help better but this would be my way of debugging the errors I really don't understand during a ts.

Comment: @Syberdoor..there are some new developments now...script is working fine when run for user through sccm...let me tell you what is happening....export-startlayout command...first identify the current user from which script has been run then..exports its respective start tiles..now sccm runs though local system account which does not have any start tiles to be exported hence nothing get exported...same command works when run from user rights..but the issue now is- how can i run script with elevated access even though it is run with user rights? can you help with this?